# Given a list with names, how to print out those names, where the first name is same?

Tags: python, list, names

I'm trying to write a function, where given names (which are always just First name, Last Name), and the function collects names with the same first name. So far I got this, but I don't know how to proceed to get back the full names in the end.

```
def same_first_name(people):
  for i in range(len(people)):
    b=people[i].split()
    print(b)
  if b[0] == b[0]:
```

for example :

```
same_first_name(["Anna Smith", "Barbara Wia", "Anna Brien"])
```

returns

```
["Anna Smith",  "Anna Brien"]
```

Comment: Its bot really clear what you are saying.. maybe provide us a input and output to help yourself help us help you...

Comment: ok okay, thank you, I will edit it

Comment: What happens if there are more then 2 Firstnames that occure two or more times?  `["A B", "A C", "B D", "B Q", "C X"]`?

Comment: then it will be also added to the output list

Comment: Are you wanting a list of all the first names eliminating the duplicates or counting how many of each are in list?

Comment: I want a list, where every person is added, who share the same first name with at least one other person in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the clarification in your comment, here is a list, where every person is added, who share the same first name with at least one other person in the list:

```py
def same_first_name(people):
    split_names = [p.split() for p in people]
    first_names_list = [p[0] for p in split_names]
    first_names_set = set(first_names_list)
    first_name_counts_dict = {
        first_name: first_names_list.count(first_name)
        for first_name in first_names_set
    }
    duplicated_first_names = [
        p for p in people if first_name_counts_dict[p.split()[0]] >= 2
    ]
    return duplicated_first_names

people = ["John Smith", "John Rogers", "Jack Jones", "Jack Smith", "Bill Bong"]

print(same_first_name(people))
```

Console output:

```
['John Smith', 'John Rogers', 'Jack Jones', 'Jack Smith']
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve, but here is a function which accepts a list of names, and makes a dictionary, where the keys are first names, and the values are lists of surnames of people who have the key as their first name:

```py
def same_first_name(people):
    split_names = [p.split() for p in people]
    first_names_set = set(p[0] for p in split_names)
    first_names_dict = {
        first_name: [p[1] for p in split_names if p[0] == first_name]
        for first_name in first_names_set
    }
    return first_names_dict

people = ["John Smith", "John Rogers", "Jack Jones", "Jack Smith", "Bill Bong"]

print(same_first_name(people))
```

Console output:

```
{'Jack': ['Jones', 'Smith'], 'Bill': ['Bong'], 'John': ['Smith', 'Rogers']}
```